Speed of satellite in elliptical orbit

A satellite $S$ orbits a planet of mass $M$ in an elliptical orbit. At perihelion, $S$ has a tangential velocity of $v_1$ and is distance $r_1$ from the planet. At aphelion, $S$ has a velocity of $v_2$ and is distance $r_2$ from the planet.

To find $v_2$ in terms of $v_1$, we can use conservation of angular momentum. $I_1 {\omega}_1 = I_2 {\omega}_2$, which means that $v_1 r_1 = v_2 r_2$, so $v_2 = \frac{r_1}{r_2}v_1$.
However, since $\frac{m{v_i}^2}{r_i} = \frac{G m M}{{r_i}^2}$ for a satellite of $m$, $$v_i = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{{r_i}}}$$
So, $v_2 = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r_2}} = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r_1 \cdot \frac{r_2}{r_1}}} = \sqrt{\frac{r_1}{r_2}} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r_1}} = \sqrt{\frac{r_1}{r_2}} v_1$.
Why do I get two different answers for $v_2$ with these methods? Why is the second method incorrect?

Velocity in elliptical orbit is not equal to circular (or called orbital) velocity.
Given $r1$ and $r_2$ as you defined, $a=(r_1+r_2)/2$, the semimajor axis of the ellipse. Then the vis viva equation for velocity (well really speed) is
$v^2=GM(\frac 2 r-\frac 1 a)   $
Notice that if perihelion and aphelion are equal the equation reduces to the circular speed equation. Let $a$ go to infinity and the escape velocity (parabolic orbit) equation is obtained.
